# sh + how to run command and set it into parameter ( VAL )

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, sh

please take look on the following commands down, ( the shell is **sh** )

something not clearly for me

when I run -  **eval echo \$arr$n** , I get the value **a** as expected

so why:  **VAL=` eval echo \$arr$n `** , and **echo $VAL** not print the same value **a** ?

set a value in arr1

```
# n=1
# eval arr$n=a
```

print a value from arr1

```
# n=1
# eval echo \$arr$n
  a
```

set **eval echo \$arr$n**  in to **VAL** , and print **$VAL**

```
# VAL=` eval echo \$arr$n `
# echo $VAL
{*}1
```

what need to fix in the command - **VAL=` eval echo \$arr$n `** , so when I do **echo $VAL** I will get the value **a**  ?

Comment: Judging from the use of `#` as a shell prompt, you're running as `root`.  Don't test code as `root`; it is dangerous.  I've only been using Unix for over thirty years, and I don't do anything as `root` unless it is absolutely necessary. It's safer, by a large margin.

Comment: Hi dont worry this is test machine , so we can do anything on that machine -:)

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a test machine, it's a bad habit to get into. Get used to sudo when you really need root access; for tests like this, you simply don't need it.

Comment: Beware of eval!  If the variable you are eval'ing can be manipulated into containing a command, eval will run it! see here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with Bash 3.2 (on Mac OS X 10.9.4) run as `sh`:

```
sh-3.2$ n=1
sh-3.2$ eval arr$n=a
sh-3.2$ eval echo \$arr$n
a
sh-3.2$ VAL=`eval echo \$arr$n`
sh-3.2$ echo $VAL
1
sh-3.2$ VAL=$(eval echo \$arr$n)
sh-3.2$ echo $VAL
a
sh-3.2$ VAL=`eval echo \$arr$n`
sh-3.2$ echo $VAL
1
sh-3.2$ VAL=`eval echo \\$arr$n`
sh-3.2$ echo $VAL
a
sh-3.2$ arr=xyz
sh-3.2$ VAL=`eval echo \$arr$n`
sh-3.2$ echo $VAL
xyz1
sh-3.2$
```

Note that there is a difference between using back-ticks and `$(…)`.  I recommend the use of `$(…)` because it is simpler to understand.  If you want to stick with back-ticks, double up the back-slashes.  (I'm not quite sure why it is behaving as it is, but that's what the empirical evidence says you need to do.)

If you want to use arrays, use arrays:

```
arr=('' a)
echo "${arr[1]}"
```